# Using joblib to parallelize predict() with a scikit-learn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

What is the recommended way to parallelize the `predict()` method of a scikit-learn pipeline?

Here is a minimal working example that illustrates the problem by attempting parallel `predict()` on the iris data using an SVM pipeline and 5 parallel jobs:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
from sklearn import datasets

# Load Iris data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
# Create a pipeline with 2 steps: scaler and SVM; train
pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), SVC()).fit(X=iris.data, y=iris.target)

# Split data array in 5 chunks
n_chunks = 5
n_samples = iris.data.shape[0]
slices = [(int(n_samples*i/n_chunks), int(n_samples*(i+1)/n_chunks)) for i in range(n_chunks)]
data_chunks = [iris.data[i[0]:i[1]] for i in slices]

# Setup 5 parallel jobs 
jobs = (delayed(pipe.predict)(array) for array in data_chunks)
parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=n_chunks)

# Run jobs: fails
results = parallel(jobs)
```

This code fails with:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function Pipeline.predict at 0x000000001746B730>: it's not the same object as sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.predict
```

However, applying parallelization to the SVM classifier directly, instead of the pipeline, works:

```
# Load Iris data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
# Create SVM classifier, train
svc = SVC().fit(X=iris.data, y=iris.target)

# Split data array in 5 chunks
n_chunks = 5
n_samples = iris.data.shape[0]
slices = [(int(n_samples*i/n_chunks), int(n_samples*(i+1)/n_chunks)) for i in range(n_chunks)]
data_chunks = [iris.data[i[0]:i[1]] for i in slices]

# Setup 5 parallel jobs 
jobs = (delayed(svc.predict)(array) for array in data_chunks)
parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=n_chunks)

# Run jobs: works
results = parallel(jobs)
```

I am able to work around the problem by essentially taking the pipeline apart: first applying scaling to the whole array, then splitting into chunks and parallelizing `svc.predict()` like above. However, it is inconvenient and generally voids advantages offered by pipelines: e.g. I have to keep track of intermediate results, and the code would have to change if additional transformer steps are added into the pipeline.

Is there a way to parallelize using pipelines directly?

Many thanks,

Aleksey